# Template Hierarchy: confused with index.php, front-page.php, home.php

Tags: template-hierarchy

I'm really confused with `index.php`, `home.php` and `front-page.php`. In many cases even though I had an `index.php`, I overwrite it with `front-page.php`. But recently, I became aware about `home.php`.

- What's the difference between the `home.php` and `index.php`?
- What's the ideal condition to use a `home.php` than an `index.php`?
- What's the ideal condition to use a `front-page.php`?
- When I'm using a `front-page.php` then what specific task an `index.php` is doing for me then?

I've read the [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in Codex. Please don't mix my question with Page Templates, I understand 'em, alHamduLILLAH.

Comment: Got @rarst with this: https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/front-page-logic/. May help you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Front page logic is one of the most confusing features in WordPress and is exceptionally hard to explain and summarize. As mentioned in comment while back I burnt unholy amount of time to put together my [front page logic cheat sheet](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/front-page-logic/) for it.

But since this is a popular thread let me try to answer those very specific questions you had.

> What's the difference between the `home.php` and `index.php`?

`home.php` is template for posts index (archive of native Post post type, which is a special case in WP). WP will attempt to look it up for index of posts, whether they are displayed at the root of the site or at dedicated posts page.

`index.php` is catch–all template. It is final choices in all branches of template hierarchy and will be picked when nothing else fits, for both archives and singular views.

Only posts index can use `home.php`, but *all* other contexts might and will use `index.php`.

> What's the ideal condition to use a `home.php` than an `index.php`

You use `home.php` to customize posts index.

You use `index.php` to provide the most generic template in your theme, suitable for display of anything.

Some themes choose to have empty `index.php` and ensure they have more specific templates for all possible cases, so it never has to be used.

> What's the ideal condition to use a `front-page.php`?

`front-page.php` is used for posts index at the root or static front page, if enabled.

It is a high priority template, so if theme has it you cannot select arbitrary template for static front page. For this reason it is almost never included in publicly released themes (which is correct).

The best use for it is in private projects, since it's easier to configure than page template.

> When I'm using a `front-page.php` then what specific task an `index.php` is doing for me then?

`index.php` is *still* a catch all template for all other cases.

If you use static front page (to which `front-page.php` will apply) then your posts page will try to use `home.php` and then `index.php`.

Answer (score 31):

The `front-page.php` file is the **site front page** template. It will always be used on your site front page, regardless of whether `get_option( 'show_on_front' )` is set to `page` or `posts`.

The `home.php` template file is the **blog posts index** template. It will always be used to display your blog posts index, regardless of whether the blog posts index is displayed on the site front page, or on a different page.

In the case that both `front-page.php` and `home.hpp` exist, and the `get_option( 'show_on_front' )` is set to `posts` (i.e., the site front page displays the blog posts index), the `front-page.php` file will take precedence over the `home.php` file.

The `index.php` file is the **default fallback template** for all contexts in the [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). It is only ever used if a more-specific template file does not exist for the current context.

The template hierarchy for the **site front page** is:

- `front-page.php`
- If `'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' )`: page hierarchy
- If `'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front' )`: blog posts index hierarchy

The template hierarchy for the **blog posts index** is:

- `home.php`
- `index.php`

The template hierarchy for **pages** is:

- Custom page template
- `page-{slug}.php`
- `page-{id}.php`
- `page.php`
- `index.php`

Comment: So, if i'm getting this right, it's not possible to use `my-template-1` template when the front page is set to latest posts and use `my-template-2` when the front is set to an static page (without coding) ?

Answer (score 19):

All this comes from a thorough reading of the [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

`home.php` is used if:

- Your site's front page is set to display a list of posts, or

  - [A static front page is set](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), and
  - A visitor goes to the page that you've defined as your "list of posts" (eg, `http://example.com/blog/`)
- And the theme has a `home.php` file

If the last condition isn't met -- ie, there is no `home.php` file in the theme -- then `index.php` will be loaded.

`front-page.php` will be used if:

- [A static front page is set](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), and
- A visitor goes to the page that you've defined as your "static home page" (ie, `http://example.com/`), and
- The theme has a `front-page.php` file

If the last condition isn't met -- ie, there is no `front-page.php` file in the theme -- then `index.php` will be loaded.

#### In summary

If you want to customize your list of posts, use `home.php`.
If you want to customize your static home page, use `front-page.php`.

Comment: `home.php` will be used for the blog posts index, regardless of location. If the front page is set to display the blog posts index, then `home.php` will be used (if `front-page.php` does not exist).

Answer (score 12):

In short:

- `index.php` is a fallback template only, in case no appropriate template was found
- `home.php` is used for the blog (a listing of recent posts)
- `front-page.php` is used for the landing-page

## The universal `index.php` template

The `index.php` template file is a fallback template. It is used as a last resort when no other more appropriate template is available. For example, if you don't have a `front-page.php` nor a `home.php` then `index.php` will be used. This is also true for missing `archive.php` or `single.php` and so on.

## Regarding `front-page.php` VS `home.php`

Now the difference between `front-page.php` and `home.php` templates is that the `front-page.php` is used, as its name suggests, as the main front-page of the site, while `home.php` is intended to be the home of the **Blog** section.

### What template will be used for my site's landing-page?

The `front-page.php` template, if present, will be used for the site's main front page (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`). If not present, then `home.php` will be used instead. If both the `front-page.php` and `home.php` template files are missing then the `index.php` fallback template will be used.

### What template will be used for my blog page?

WordPress allows you to have a "Blog" page (which will list recent posts) on a *different page* than the landing-page (e.g. `http://www.example.com/blog/`). So if this is the case on your site, then the Blog page will always use the `home.php` template. If `home.php` doesn't exist then the `index.php` fallback template will be used.

## How to configure the landing-page and blog page?

To configure what content to show on your front page, go to the **WordPress Admin**, under **Tools > Reading**, there you can configure the "*Front page displays*" to show a static page, or your latest posts.

In the case you choose to display a static page on the front page, then you also have the possibility to set which page to use as a placeholder for the Blog page (which will use the `home.php` template):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

taken from [Wordpress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

> **Home Page display**
>
> By default, WordPress sets your site’s home page to display your
>   latest blog posts. This page is called the blog posts index. You can
>   also set your blog posts to display on a separate static page. The
>   template file home.php is used to render the blog posts index, whether
>   it is being used as the front page or on separate static page. If
>   home.php does not exist, WordPress will use index.php.
>
> 1. **home.php**
> 2. **index.php**
>
> > Note: If front-page.php exists, it will override the home.php template.
>
> **Front Page display**
>
> The front-page.php template file is used to render your site’s front
>   page, whether the front page displays the blog posts index (mentioned
>   above) or a static page. The front page template takes precedence over
>   the blog posts index (home.php) template. If the front-page.php file
>   does not exist, WordPress will either use the home.php or page.php
>   files depending on the setup in Settings → Reading. If neither of
>   those files exist, it will use the index.php file.
>
> **1. front-page.php** – Used for both “your latest posts” or “a static page”
>   as set in the front page displays section of Settings → Reading.
>
> **2. home.php** – If WordPress cannot find front-page.php and “your latest
>   posts” is set in the front page displays section, it will look for
>   home.php. Additionally, WordPress will look for this file when the
>   posts page is set in the front page displays section.
>
> **3. page.php** – When
>   “front page” is set in the front page displays section.
>
> **4. index.php** –
>   When “your latest posts” is set in the front page displays section but
>   home.php does not exist or when front page is set but page.php does
>   not exist.
>
> As you can see, there are a lot of rules to what path
>   WordPress takes. Using the chart above is the best way to determine
>   what WordPress will display.

Template hierarchy chart:
[image: Wordpress template hierarchy]

Answer (score 3):

I decided to test which template is used for each of the following pages when the various Front page displays options are set.

- example.net
- example.net/home/
- example.net/blog/

The results are quite long, but can be used as a reference or cheat-sheet.

[image: Front page displays]

Source: [How do the front-page.php and home.php templates differ in WordPress?](https://wpcarrot.com/2017/04/25/how-do-the-front-page-php-and-home-php-templates-differ-in-wordpress/)

**Note to editor:** I tried to copy and paste the tables here but markdown format is required instead of HTML. Please convert to markdown if you can.