# Confused by the behaviour of "front page" / "home" templates

Tags: theme-development, templates, frontpage

I stumbled upon a confusing issue while trying to customize the appearance of the front page of my blog (`blog.example.com`) without changing the behaviour of the other blog posts index pages (`blog.example.com/page/3`).

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to add a template for the front page that doesn't affect the other list pages:

- according to [wphierarchy.com](http://wphierarchy.com/) and to the rather confusingly worded codex entry, it looks like `front-page.php` is what I'm after, but if I provide that, the blog posts index pages are affected by it as well!
- if I modify `home.php`, both the home page and the index pages are affected, as correctly documented
- adding a custom page template and setting the front page to use a page with that template set doesn't work either! the index pages still end up calling the `page-foo.php` template

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get you on this. `page/3` is simply page number 3 of `blog.example.com` and should by default use the same template as page one. This is a paged page, not a separate page

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110349/template-hierarchy-confused-with-index-php-front-page-php-home-php

Comment: Thank you both, I see that I just completely misunderstood the entire thing! @PieterGoosen, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. I think it's good to leave this question here as it might help anybody else who would be having the same confusion. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted my comment as an answer. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this all wrong :-)

- `blog.example.com` is page one
- `blog.example.com/page/3` is page number 3 of `blog.example.com`

So this not a new page, but a paged page. By default, this all pages in a paged sequence will use the same template as the first page