# Theme's page.php and index.php template files are confusing me

Tags: page-template, homepage, frontpage

I was watching a WordPress course, the explainer has `page.php` and `index.php` theme template files. Which means the `page.php` must load the home page, but the home page is loaded with `index.php`!

I used his same files, but I have `page.php` loading the home page!
How does his setup override it but mine doesn't?

Comment: The real homepage is loaded as `front-page.php`. If it's not available to load, then WordPress will move onto `index.php` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### WordPress Template Hierarchy:

You should read about [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110349/template-hierarchy-confused-with-index-php-front-page-php-home-php) also has some related answers.

#### Typical Case:

In your case, **the most likely scenario** is:

> The explainer had set the latest posts as the home page (this is the default option) and you have set a static front page as home page. Since his is blog archive, it's being loaded by `index.php` and yours is a page, so that's being loaded by `page.php`.

This is just a typical scenario, but there may be other settings that are affecting which template file is being loaded.

#### Changing the default setting:

If the above is your scenario, then changing the following setting from  WordPress `wp-admin -> Settings -> Reading -> Your latest posts` (then `Save Changes`) will make it the same for you and the explainer. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but you get it wrong, mine get loaded by page.php and his with index.php

Comment: Well man you're rock, but how I can set the home page like him ?

Comment: Well of course bro, I just new to this site .